# Changing Engineering Specialisations after Undergrad

Tags: masters, undergraduate, engineering

I am wondering whether it is generally possible to change engineering specialisations after completing a bachelors degree.

I'm currently completing a bachelor of engineering with honours in chemical and materials engineering. I am interested in completing a master's in aerospace engineering as I have a significant interest in aspects of jet propulsion.

I feel there would be a lot of transferable skills which may help me - i.e. thermodynamics, fluid mechanics, pumps and turbines, heat transfer, and materials; although they would be applied in a different context.

I guess my question is, as long as there are some transferable skills to your field of research, can one change specialisation without significant difficulty at the postgraduate level?

Comment: I suggest that this is a different question to the linked, which focus on research postgrad.
but Engineering (bachelors->masters) is coursework, and going on to do masters after bachelors, at the same institution, is expected. Like going premed->med, or prelaw->law. And because of this candidates entry is not nesc assessed on anything other than where they have completed the pre-req undergrad. And universities can have streamlined processes for changing specializations, due to knowing the exact content of all courses concerned -- unlike in research degrees. I know mine does, it's +4-8 units.

Comment: Possibly though the "Reference" question linked just needs to be improved to be better for purely coursework degrees.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is possible to switch disciplines within engineering between the bachelor's and master's programs.

However, this does depend a lot on the nature of the programs and how closely related they are. For instance, it's probably easier to go from chemical to biomedical engineering than it is to electrical or civil.

It's also worth pointing out that you may need to take additional coursework that candidates with a degree in the discipline do not.